# On a proof of a number field theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

- $\textbf{Theorem}\ $For every integer $n\geq 2$, let $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ be the cyclotomic field generated by the primitive $n$-th roots of $1$. Suppose $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_m]=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ with $m<n$. Then $m$ is odd and $n=2m$.

What I know:

- the degree $[\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]:\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$;
- the discriminant $d_n=\operatorname{disc}(\zeta_n)$ divides $n^{\phi(n)}$;
- a rational prime $p$ ramifies in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ if and only if $p$ divides $d_n$.

What I know is sufficient to prove the Theorem? If yes, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one-possible approach:

If $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ by comparing degrees we get that $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$.

But, it's easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{(n,m)})$, so we can actually assume WLOG that $n\mid m$.

But, factor $m=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_\ell^{e_\ell}$ so then by assumption, with the possibility of reordering, $n=p_1^{f_1}\cdots p_k^{f_k}$ with $k\leqslant\ell$ and $f_j\leqslant e_j$. So, then,

$$\varphi(m)=p_1^{e_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_\ell^{e_\ell-1}(p_\ell-1)$$

and

$$\varphi(n)=p_1^{f_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_k^{f_k-1}(p_k-1)$$

By assumption, $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$. But, upon division we find that this implies that

$$p_1^{e_1-f_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k-f_k}p_{k+1}^{e_{k+1}-1}(p_k-1)\cdots p^{e_\ell-1}(p_\ell-1)=1$$

Clearly we must have that $e_i-f_i=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ and $e_i-1=0$ for $i=k+1,\ldots,\ell$ and also that $p_i-1=1$ for $i=k+1,\ldots,\ell$. Thus, if $k\ne\ell$ This last condition automatically implies that $p_i=1$ for $i=k+1,\ldots,\ell$ and since the $p_i$ are distinct this actually implies that $\ell=k+1$ and $p_\ell=2$. So then, it's easy to see that

$$m=2 p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$$

and

$$n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$$

which is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: It might be simpler to just say that $\mu_n=\mu_m$ without going through integers and units

Comment: @user8268 How exactly does one deduce that you have equality of roots of unity from the extensions being equal, in another way than the one I wrote? Maybe I'm having a momentary lapse in creativity, but $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-5})$ but $\sqrt{-5}$ is not even conjugate to $i$ or $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: well, $K$ contains the same roots of $1$ as $K$  (I don't get your counterexample; sure, the fields are equal, so they have the same elements)

Comment: @user8268 Oh, I see. Instead of going to the integers, you can just stop at the units of whole field :).

Comment: @AlexYoucis What is $\mu_n$?

Comment: @bateman Roots of unity.

Comment: @user8268 I think it should be good now.

Comment: Actually, now you even don't need to mention $\mu_n$ :) $\phi(m)$ and $\phi(n)$ are the degrees of the extensions. [in the first short version of your answer you were (I thought) using that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ contains exactly $2n$-th roots of $1$ for $n$ odd and $n$-th roots for $n$ even - though it's a thing that probably needs a proof]

Comment: @user8268 Of course, but I didn't feel like editing more haha. Changed it.

Comment: @AlexYoucis If $n$ is even, then $m=2n$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{2n}]$ are not equal. What am i missing?

Comment: @bateman I don't know. What is the problem with that? What I proved above shows that if $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ and $m\ne n$, then $m=2n$ with $n$ odd.

Comment: @AlexYoucis oh sorry, the primes are all distinct and the only prime equal to $2$ is $p_l$, hence $n$ is odd, ok, thank you

Comment: @bateman No problem :)